# Hand-over-hand locking: list_sorted_insert at the end of the list vs. in the middle

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list, locking

Hand-over-hand locking is also known as lock coupling or fine-grain locking.  It's where you have a lock per node, instead of just locking the entire list with one lock.

Anyways, I wrote a thread-safe linked list and I want to justify that I've locked the least amount of locks for the least amount of time to avoid deadlock and corrupted data...in addition to giving the steps I took to locking and unlocking.

I had no problem giving my justification for list_pop, list_push_end and list_sorted_insert (inserting in the middle).  Unfortunately, the way I implemented my listed_sorted_insert (inserting at the end) is almost identical to inserting in the middle.  I originally put they were the same until I've been reading that I'm doing this incorrectly.

```
To avoid both deadlock and corrupted data...  
Accomplishing both of these is significantly different for inserting 
at the end vs. in the middle.
```

How is inserting at the end of the list "significantly different" than inserting in the middle?  Where am I going wrong in my code below?  I'm still  not convinced they're the same except for an if statement.

```
void list_sorted_insert(list_t *list, int value)
{
    list_item_t *item;

    assert(list != NULL);

    list_item_t *new_item = NEW_ITEM(new_item);

    new_item->value = value;

    LOCK_LIST(list);
    LOCK_ITEM(list);

    if (list->first == NULL || value < list->first->value) 
    {
        // special case inserting at beginning of list
        new_item->next = list->first;
        list->first = new_item;

        if (list->last == NULL) list->last = new_item;

        list->count++;

        UNLOCK_ITEM(list);
    }
    else
    {
        item = list->first;
        LOCK_ITEM(item);
        UNLOCK_ITEM(list);

        while (item->next != NULL && item->next->value < value)
        {
            #ifdef HOH_LOCKING
            list_item_t * pItem = item;
            #endif
            LOCK_ITEM(item->next);
            item = item->next;
            UNLOCK_ITEM(pItem);
        }

        //sched_yield();
        new_item->next = item->next;
        item->next = new_item;

        UNLOCK_ITEM(item);

        LOCK_ITEM(list);

        if (item->next == NULL) {
            list->last = new_item;
        }

        list->count++;

        UNLOCK_ITEM(list);
    }

    UNLOCK_LIST(list);
}
```

The only problem I see is between unlocking the item then locking the list (couldn't a thread come in between those statements and do_bad_stuff?), but this isn't related to the difference between inserting in the middle vs inserting at the end.

Does anyone know what I am missing in my code and why inserting at the end needs to be significantly different to avoid deadlock and corrupted data?

EDIT: More relevant code

```
#define LOCK_MUTEX(mutex) assert(pthread_mutex_lock(&(mutex)) == 0)
#define UNLOCK_MUTEX(mutex) assert(pthread_mutex_unlock(&(mutex)) == 0)
#define LOCK(hasMutexPtr) LOCK_MUTEX((hasMutexPtr)->mutex)
#define UNLOCK(hasMutexPtr) UNLOCK_MUTEX((hasMutexPtr)->mutex)

#ifdef HOH_LOCKING
    #define LOCK_LIST(listPtr)
    #define UNLOCK_LIST(listPtr)
    #define LOCK_ITEM(item) LOCK(item)
    #define UNLOCK_ITEM(item) UNLOCK(item)

    #define NEW_ITEM(item) (list_item_t *)malloc(sizeof(list_item_t)); \
        assert(item != NULL); \
        pthread_mutex_init(&(item->mutex), NULL)
#else
    #define LOCK_LIST(listPtr) LOCK((listPtr))
    #define UNLOCK_LIST(listPtr) UNLOCK((listPtr))
    #define LOCK_ITEM(item) 
    #define UNLOCK_ITEM(item)

    #define NEW_ITEM(item) (list_item_t *)malloc(sizeof(list_item_t)); \
        assert(item != NULL)
#endif

// Struct for elements in a singly linked list
typedef struct list_item_s
{
    int value;                  // value stored in list element
    struct list_item_s *next;   // pointer to next list element
    #ifdef HOH_LOCKING
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    #endif
} list_item_t;

//*******************************************************
// struct for a list made up of list_item_t elements
typedef struct list_s
{
    int count;                  // number of items in the list
    struct list_item_s *first;  // pointer to first element in list
    struct list_item_s *last;   // pointer to last element in list
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} list_t;
```

Comment: It is difficult to say whether the code is correct without knowing how other functions access the list. Post all relevant code, including struct definitions.

Comment: @ EOF just updated the code with some structs and macros I use in the `list_sorted_insert`.

Comment: Wow, that macro-gore. You *do* realize that putting side-effecting code into `assert()` is a horrific idea?

Comment: Sorry @EOF could you elaborate? I believe you, I just want to know why.

Comment: `man assert`: *assert()  is  implemented  as  a  macro; if the expression tested has side-effects, program behavior will be different depending on whether NDEBUG  is defined.  This may create Heisenbugs which go away when debugging is turned on.*